# Docker building a .net core application that references projects in different folder

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I'm attempting to write a Dockerfile that builds my .NET Core 2.2 console app `project-microservice-logger.csproj`. I'm getting some build errors, and I beleive this is because the Dockerfile I'm trying to build is residing in the directory that holds the `project-microservice-logger.csproj`

But this project has some references to projects that are in a different directory.

```
/company/project-common/project-common-database/project-common-database.csproj
/company/project-microservices/project-microservice-logger/project-microservice-logger.csproj
```

When I issue the command, while in the `/company/project-microservices/project-microservice-logger` directory, I'm getting errors like

> The type or namespace name 'Common' does not exist in the namespace

Since I can build it just fine, I know it has something due to Dockers build context, and that it can't find the file.

My Docker file is nothing special, essentially just taken from some of the Docker templates for .NET Core that are readily available online.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "logging.dll"]
```

I'm open to making changes to how we make project references, if it's a better solution for future Continuous Deployment situations.

All the code is in one repository, but separated into different solutions at the moment (core, micro-services, and web)

**Versions**
.NET Core 2.2
Docker for Mac / Version 2.0.0.2

Comment: in visual studio, select the project reference from other folder, hit f4 and change property to copy to local. Save all files. That should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the `publish` logic in a shell script, and the docker image uses the files built from that as its code base.

This script assumes the following folder structure:

> Solution-Folder/build/this-build-script.sh
>   Solution-Folder/MyProject/MyProjectName.csproj

```
BUILD_MODE="Release"
DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG="latest"

readonly BUILD_MODE
readonly DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG

publish_and_build_image()
{
  PROJECT_DIR=$1
  PROJECT_FILE_NAME=$2
  DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME=$3

  echo "Publishing project $PROJECT_FILE_NAME ..."
  echo
  dotnet publish "..\\$PROJECT_DIR\\$PROJECT_FILE_NAME" --configuration $BUILD_MODE --verbosity quiet

  echo "Building docker image $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG ..."
  docker build --tag=$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG "../$PROJECT_DIR" --quiet

  #echo
  #echo -e "\033[32m $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG built \033[0m"
}

publish_and_build_image "MyProject" "MyProjectName.csproj" "my-docker-img-name"
```